# Magento Admin Custum Form with wrong display

Tags: forms, magento, zend-framework, backend

I am working on Magento 1.7.0.2 and i have made a custum Grid/Form BO.   [image]
But this is how my form looks like  :

Can you help ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At your custom modules Form file in below directory

```
local\YOUR_NAMESPACE\MODULE_NAME\Block\Adminhtml\MODULE_NAME\Edit\Tab\Form.php
```

Should be like

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $brandModel = Mage::registry('brand_data');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('brand_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Item information')));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Title'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'title',
    ));
```

}

hope this will sure work for you.